# Parse.com: I want to show the user recent chats

Tags: parse-platform

Hi Basically I do the following:

- I let the use have different chat rooms with people.
- So they can have chat room 1 where they speak with person 1 and chat room 2 where they speak with person 2.
- I want to show the user their recent chats grouped by chat room. So show them most recent message from chat room 1 and most recent message from chat room 2.
- When user gets a message in a chat, I want to notify them about this message.
  How do I do the above?